# write method in R -where does the file end up?

Tags: r, for-loop

It seems forloops in R do not work exactly the way I thought:

```
 myVector <-c(0,0,0)
> for (i in 0:0){
 s1<-sum(e1*data3[,i]);
 s2<-sum(e2*data3[,i]);
 s3<-sum(e3*data3[,i]);
 hilf <- cbind(s1,s2,s3);
 myVector <- cbind(myVector, help);
 }
```

works but the result is:

```
> myVector
      myVector s1 s2 s3
 [1,]        0  0  0  0
```

now, I would expect something like 3 zeros.
Does anyone know why I get four dimensions instead of three?

Comment: this is incoherent, try reading your own code

Comment: Is `help` the same object as `hilf`?

Comment: If `help` and `hifl` are the same, then it looks like you're `cbind()`g 3 things together... and then 1 more... and 3+1=4... nothing to do with a loop at all...

Comment: And your question title has nothing to do with the actual question...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Despite the fact that the code you posted is, eh, interesting, what is happening here has nothing to do with `for`-loops.   It is your multiple `cbind` statements.

you are attempting to combine a tall 1x3 matrix with a vector of length 3.  This will cause `myVector` to lose it's last two elements when combined, as you witness in the output you have pasted.

instead, if you transpose one of the two (either `myVector` or `hilf`) you might get something more in line with what you are looking for.

#### I am assuming that by `help` you meant `hilf`.